# why is printf called twice? and even it seems random randomly?

Tags: c, printf, malloc

I am trying to make program that reads a .bin file and find a "human made characters". I haven't got far because every time i try to print buffer of found character it prints it twice or it prints those that i should not. I found out that only *fflush(stdout)* prints it once. Now i am trying to print it as string *printf(%s, buffer)* and I was trying to do it with *for()* (did not work). And now i have no idea what to do.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int l = 3;
    if(argc >= 2){
        l = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    char* buffer = (char*) malloc((l + 1) * sizeof(char));
    int ch;
    int i = 0;

    while ((ch=getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (i == l) {
            buffer[i] = '\0';
            printf("%s", buffer);
            i = 0;
        }
        if (ch >= ' ' && ch <= '~') {
            buffer[i] = putchar(ch);
            i++;
        } else {
            printf("\n");
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `buffer[i] = putchar(ch);` - you probably meant `buffer[i] = ch;`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you ran amok is because you are not breaking out of the `while` loop. Here is the code that should `break`.

```
 if (i == l) {
            buffer[i] = '\0';
            printf("%s", buffer);
            i = 0;
 }
```

So before you put on that closing brace, break out of the while loop. You do not need the while loop anymore. Here is the revised `if` block:

```
 if (i == l) {
            buffer[i] = '\0';
            printf("%s", buffer);
            i = 0;
            break;
 }
```

Because you did not put in the break, it jumped to the `else`.